# Need to get a Specified word or value from a response string

Tags: string, api, lua

I am trying to get a value from a third party device response.

the response is as follows;

{"p_targetId":0,"p_cmd":"getProductListSaved","p_rspStatus":"SUCCESS","p_msg":"","p_data":[{"globalproductlistsavedID":"1","ProductCustomName":"GDC","ProductIp":"192.168.168.**","ProductMask":"255.255.255.0","ProductIsDhcp":"0","ProductIpTwo":"192.168.168.**","ProductMaskTwo":"255.255.255.0","ProductIsDhcpTwo":"0","ProductSupported_ProductSupportedID":"3","ProductLogin":"","ProductPassword":"","ProductIdOverride":"1"}]}

In my lua script am writing, with data representing the above response;

name, value = string.match(data,"(.+):(.+)")
Controls.DeviceName.String = tostring(value)

from this am always getting; "1"}]}

Is it possible to specify which part of the response I want to extract? example: "GDC" or "192.168.168.**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a JSON String.
So the best/fastest way is JSON support for Lua.
The Linux Editor NeoVIM (nvim) has LuaJIT and JSON support.
And that can make things so easy...
[image: NeoVIM run Lua to decode a JSON String]
( Also available for Windows, macOS and Android (With Termux) )
Visit: https://github.com/neovim/neovim

Comment: Is there a way to do it through Visual Studio Code?  Currently am trying to use string.find() and string.sub() functions.

Comment: a, b = string.find(data,"globalproductlistsavedID")
        b = b + 3
        c, d = string.find(data,"ProductIp")
        c = c -3
        d = d + 3
        e, f = string.find(data,"ProductCustomName")
        e = e - 3
        f = f + 3
        g, h = string.find(data,"ProductMask")
        g = g - 3

        Controls.DeviceName.String = string.sub(data,f,c)
        Controls.DeviceIP.String = tostring(string.sub(data,d,g))
        Controls.DeviceID.String = tostring(string.sub(data,b,e))

Comment: was wondering if there is a simpler way

Comment: ```json.decode()``` returns (convert JSON String to) a Lua Table - What please is a simpler way? - To wrote an own Converter that takes care of all Possibilities? - Like JSON Comments (```/* Hi There */```) and different Datatypes in Key/Value (String/Number/Table) Pairs

Comment: with string.find( and string.sub() have managed to get what I needed. Thank You Koyaanisqatsi